# getting undefined error in including dependency at karma.conf.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, karma-jasmine

I am trying to include all the dependencies in karma.conf.js

```
'../node_modules/**/*.js',
 '../bower_components/**/*.js',
```

Here, i have included all. getting error as module is not defined error.

So i have tried following order

```
 '../bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js',
       '../bower_components/angular/angular.js',
       '../bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
```

So it is working fine but i need to all dependencies. It seems, including all the modules by order wise.

How can i define all dependencies in karma.conf.js